# Why my socket client listner on is not working?

Tags: next.js, websocket, socket.io

I have this client-side component that submits two fields to a listener at my server and then pushes the user to a room page

```js
  const createRoom = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget)

    socket.emit('create room', {
      name: formData.get('name'),
      room: formData.get('room'),
    })

    console.log(socket.id)

    router.push('/room')
  }
```

at the room page it listens to an emit that is triggered when the user joins the room, but nothing comes at data

```js
'use client'

import { socket } from '@/libs/socket'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Room() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('room socket id: ' + socket.id)

    socket.on('user entered', (data) => {
      setData(data)
    })
  }, [])

  return <h1>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</h1>
}
```

and here is the server

```js
// app setup
const app = express()
app.use(cors())

const server = app.listen(3333, () => {
  console.log('app listening at http://localhost:3333')
})

// socket setup
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('create room', (data) => {
    socket.join(data.room)

    socket
      .to(data.room)
      .emit('user entered', { message: `${data.name} entrou` })
  })

  console.log(`new socket connection: ${socket.id}`)
})
```

here is the versions of the libs i'm using

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.3.2",
    "@types/react": "18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.6",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.7",
    "next": "13.4.7",
    "postcss": "8.4.24",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  },
```

I wanted to receive the message that the server is triggering